# Using Apple Pencil as a stylus with older unsupported iPads

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil

I have some old iPads that I want to use for Zoom meetings. I want to use one as a whiteboard, drawing diagrams in the Notes app and showing them on screen.

Can I use an Apple Pencil (either gen 1 or gen 2) as a basic stylus for drawing in the Notes app? I don't need any fancy features, just the ability to draw.

I don't have an Apple Pencil to test, but I'm willing to buy one if it will work. Here are the iPads I have:

1. iPad 2 with iOS 9.3.5
2. iPad mini 4 with iOS 13.5
3. iPad Air 2 with iOS 13.5

Comment: The Apple Retail app does an amazing job at listing what’s compatible if you add each device to your AppleID. Is it possible to use that to check compatibility? All of them will use capacitive touch stylus and my hunch is none will work with the first gen pencil. For sure none will work with the second version that charges wirelessly.

Comment: There are other third-party styluses, which are usually cheaper, and which simply provide a 'finger', without the more advanced capabilities of the Apple Pencil.

Comment: @benwiggy I’ll be getting a new iPad Pro along with supported Apple Pencil. I am wondering if the same can be used with older gen iPads.

Comment: If you're getting the pencil anyway, you'll be able to test and let us know for sure! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What devices are compatible with Apple Pencil?

The original Apple Pencil, manufactured from 2015 on with the round body design and Lightning connector is compatible with the following devices:

```
iPad Air (3rd generation)
‌iPad‌ mini (5th generation)
‌iPad‌ (7th generation)
‌iPad‌ (6th generation)
‌iPad Pro‌ 12.9-inch (2nd generation)
‌iPad Pro‌ 12.9-inch (1st generation)
‌iPad Pro‌ 10.5-inch
‌iPad Pro‌ 9.7-inch
```

Looks like you just missed it. This table is from this [Mac Rumor site.](https://www.macrumors.com/guide/apple-pencil/)

The new pencil is compatible with only the new iPad Pros. The linked site is dated March 4th 2020 so it is very recent.

Comment: Any capacitive stylus will work with any iPad - since it simulates the human touch, but none of the benefits of Apple engineering are present - those help for touch events where fine motor control is easier with a stylus but don’t get the angle and enhanced refresh rate of Apple Pencil.